# How to make a JSP-Uploaded file accessible by anyone?

Tags: jsp, servlets, localhost

I'm creating a JSP/servlet based web app that uploads a file to a folder on the server.
But when I hit the link to the uploaded file, I'm not able to access it.
E.g. I have uploaded the file at  `/Projects/MyFiles/file.html`
when I try to access that file using
`localhost:8083/Projects/MyFiles/file.html` it doesn't work.

Can anyone please help?

here is my code

```
@WebServlet("/uploadIDCM")
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String finalString = "Yet to";
        if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)){
            try {
                List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
                for(FileItem item : multiparts){
                    if(!item.isFormField()){
                        String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                        item.write( new File("/Projects/MyFiles/" + File.separator + name));
                    }
                }
                finalString = "Success";
                request.setAttribute("msg", "File Uploaded Successfully");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                finalString = "Exception" + ex.toString();
                request.setAttribute("msg", "File Upload Failed due to " + ex);
            }
        }else{
            finalString = "No file found";
            request.setAttribute("msg","No File found");
        }

    }
}
```

index.js file is

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>IDCM Builds</title>
</head>
<body>
    <Center>
        <P>Upload the iOS or Android file(s) here. Upload one by one, or all at once of a specific type</P>
        <P>For .html and plist files, destination folder is determined by the File Type option you use below</P>
        <P><B>Note:</B> .html, .plist, .ipa or .apk extensions only accepted as valid files</P>
            <form action="uploadIDCM" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <table border=1><tr><Td><label for="type">File(s) Type :</label></td>
                    <td><select name="ftype">
                        <option value="iOS_Build">iOS_Build</option>
                        <option value="Android_Build">Android_Build</option>
                    </select></td></tr>
                    <tr><Td><label for="file">Upload File(s):</label></Td>
                        <Td><input type="file" name="file[]" multiple ></Td></tr>
                </table>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </Center>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We need code and more information to work with. Im not much of a judge, so I never really downvote or close or anything, but a good amount of users here WILL vote to close questions, quite quickly infact, so that the site is "clean"

Comment: @Tay, I've updated it with my code. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Make the physical path on the OS:  /Projects/MyFiles/ readable by everyone, for starters.